# Askfirst in shell

Tags: linux, shell, embedded, embedded-linux

I came across an error in an open source software called `askfirst` while working on a embedded device.

I know askfirst is used to run commands based on user input on stdin.

But when I press ctrl + \ during askfirst process (which is used to provide serial connection to device after booting up) it triggers a SIGQUIT to the process which generates a core dump file.

But in the askfirst handler file there is nothing related to the above mentioned shortcut.

I need to know why this core dump is generated and if there is a way to prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a feature (or bug) in `askfirst`. You can send `SIGQUIT` to any process running in a terminal by pressing `Ctrl-\`.

It is, instead, a feature of the terminal. You can use `stty -a` to see which key presses generate which signals:

```shell
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
...
```

There is some more detailed information about the exact mechanism in the answer to this question: [In detail, what happens when you press Ctrl-C in a terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993444/in-detail-what-happens-when-you-press-ctrl-c-in-a-terminal) The same mechanisms apply to `Ctrl-\`.

If you want to disable core dumps (in the current shell), you can use:

```shell
$ ulimit -c 0
```

If you wanted to have that happen every time you logged in, you could add that command to your `~/.profile` file.